# how to generate words onclick?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create an html page that contains a title, and when we click on the title it generates words underneath it. But the code I have is only working for the first click, and it's also deleting the title. So my question is, how can I make it generate words under the title without deleting it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>function JavaScript</title>
    <script>
    var k = 0;
    function bla(){
        var ph = ["red ","blue","black","green","yellow"];
        if(k <= ph.length ){
            document.write(ph[k]);
            k++;
        }
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1 onclick="bla();">Click here</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "generating words"? Do you just want to print each word from your array, or create a paragraph with multiple combinations of those words?

Comment: printing the words  like a paragraph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any `document.write` statement that runs after the page finishes loading will create a new page and overwrite all of the content of the current page. This is almost certainly not what you intend to have happen. You should therefore avoid using `document.write` in situations such as this

so try add a element and then write into them like this

```
<h1 onclick="bla();">Click here</h1>
<span id="test"></span>
```

JS:

```
 if(k <= ph.length ){
        //document.write(ph[k]);
         document.getElementById("test").innerText+=" "+ ph[k];;
        k++;
      }
```

[JS Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/psm2X/1/)

Answer (score 1):

This may be what you need:

```
var k = 0;

function bla() {
    var ph = ["red", "blue", "black", "green", "yellow"];

    if (k < ph.length) {
        var p = document.createElement('p');
        p.innerHTML = ph[k];
        document.body.appendChild(p);
        k++;
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/p5rLX/

It will write each word into its own paragraph.

Comment: is it possible to print the words one beside another with spaces between them ?